# Stored proc to find missing data for range of dates

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a stored proc which would fetch out missing data for the period

Following is the input to Storedprocedure

```
@yearDisplayStart
@quarterDisplayStart
@monthDisplayStart
@weekDisplayStart
@runDate
```

For example I need to find out whether the data is available between yearDisplayStart and quarterDisplayStart ,then quarterDisplayStart and monthDisplayStart then monthDisplayStart and weekDisplayStart then weekDisplayStart and runDate and return the missing data from each range.

runDate - 08/22/2014

yearDisplayStart 1/15/2014 - 08/22/2014 
quarterDisplayStart 7/1/2014 - 08/22/2014
monthDisplayStart 08/21/2014 - 08/22/2014

Find out whats missing between 1/15/2014 and 7/1/2014
Find out whats missing between 7/1/2014 and 08/21/2014

add to the list of missing dates..Also I need to take care of getting only the Weekdays got these dates.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this to create a table with a list of generated dates (+/- 50 years, for instance) and then select against, or rather join, against that.

e.g. from here: http://michaelmorley.name/how-to/create-date-dimension-table-in-sql-server

you can generate a table like this:

```
/** Create Date Dimension Table **/
/* Create First numbers table for key generation */
CREATE TABLE Numbers_Small (Number INT);

INSERT INTO Numbers_Small
VALUES (0)
    ,(1)
    ,(2)
    ,(3)
    ,(4)
    ,(5)
    ,(6)
    ,(7)
    ,(8)
    ,(9);
GO

/* Create Second numbers table for key generation */
CREATE TABLE Numbers_Big (Number_Big BIGINT);

INSERT INTO Numbers_Big (Number_Big)
SELECT (tenthousands.number * 10000 + thousands.number * 1000 + hundreds.number * 100 + tens.number * 10 + ones.number) AS number_big
FROM numbers_small tenthousands
    ,numbers_small thousands
    ,numbers_small hundreds
    ,numbers_small tens
    ,numbers_small ones;
GO

/* Create Date Dimension Table */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate] (
    [DateKey] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ,[Day] [char](10) NULL
    ,[DayOfWeek] [smallint] NULL
    ,[DayOfMonth] [smallint] NULL
    ,[DayOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[PreviousDay] [datetime] NULL
    ,[NextDay] [datetime] NULL
    ,[WeekOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[Month] [char](10) NULL
    ,[MonthOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[QuarterOfYear] [smallint] NULL
    ,[Year] [int] NULL
    );
GO

/* Create Date Key and Date Fields */
INSERT INTO [DimDate] (
    DateKey
    ,DATE
    )
SELECT number_big
    ,DATEADD(day, number_big, '1900-01-01') AS DATE
FROM numbers_big
WHERE DATEADD(day, number_big, '1900-01-01') BETWEEN '1900-01-01'
        AND '2030-12-31'
ORDER BY number_big;
GO

/* Update all other fields with appropriate data. */
UPDATE [DimDate]
SET Day = DATENAME(DW, DATE)
    ,DayOfWeek = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE)
    ,DayOfMonth = DAY(DATE)
    ,DayOfYear = DATEPART(DY, DATE)
    ,PreviousDay = DATEADD(DAY, - 1, DATE)
    ,NextDay = DATEADD(DAY, 1, DATE)
    ,WeekOfYear = DATEPART(WK, DATE)
    ,Month = DATENAME(MONTH, DATE)
    ,MonthOfYear = MONTH(DATE)
    ,QuarterOfYear = DATEPART(Q, DATE)
    ,Year = YEAR(DATE);
GO

/* Drop Temp Tables */
DROP TABLE Numbers_Small;

DROP TABLE Numbers_Big;
```